# Representing tree structure in kdb

Tags: kdb

How would I represent the below tree structure with the values in each node in kdb?

```
a    : 4
 b   : 3
  c  : 1
  d  : 2
 e   : 7
  f  : 5
   g : 2
```

I would need to setup a function to sum the values at the nodes too.
Any tips appreciated.

Comment: One approach is discussed in this paper:
http://archive.vector.org.uk/art10500340 Check section 2.Trees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches you can try.

For ex: TreeTable: table having parent and child column.

A treetable is a table with additional properties.

Firstly, the records of the table are related hierarchically. Thus, a record may have one or more child-records, which may in turn have children. If a record has a parent, it has exactly one. A record without a parent is called a root record. A record without any children is called a leaf record. A record with children is called a node record.

Following paper explains TreeTable. http://archive.vector.org.uk/art10500340

Answer (score 2):

A nested-dictionary approach would be:

```
q)dict.a.b.c:1
q)dict.a.b.d:2
q)dict.a.b[`]:3
q)dict.a[`]:4

q)dict.a.e.f.g:2
q)dict.a.e.f[`]:5
q)dict.a.e[`]:7
```

/note that it is important that each node is defined starting at the deepest nodes and working backwards to the top level nodes.

/to see the hierarchy use dict.a or dict.a.e etc, or more dynamically use

```
q)@/[dict;`a]
| 4
b| ``c`d!3 1 2
e| ``f!(7;``g!5 2)
```

/to get the values at individual nodes

```
q)first @/[dict;`a`e`f]
5
q)first @/[dict;`a`e`f`g]
2
```

/to find all values under a node

```
q){raze $[99h=type x;.z.s each x;x]}dict.a
4 3 1 2 7 5 2

q){raze $[99h=type x;.z.s each x;x]}@/[dict;`a`e]
7 5 2
```

/to sum all values under a node

```
q)sum {raze $[99h=type x;.z.s each x;x]}dict.a
24

q)sum {raze $[99h=type x;.z.s each x;x]}@/[dict;`a`e]
14
```

Obviously these can all be wrapped up into nice neat functions if necessary.

Comment: how would you create a function to detect a cyclic dependency / loop from a structure such as this?

Comment: what does a cyclic dependency look like? Can you provide a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

IMO it depends on what how you plan to "query" the tree, and what you want out of it - can you elaborate further? Do you want sub-trees? E.g. if you query for "a" will it give you "4" OR the whole sub-tree (in this case it's the whole tree).

If memory isn't an issue, or your tree is small, you could could have either a nested dictionary of dictionaries, with a function that recurses inside the dictionaries, or you could have the letter symbols as the key of a single dictionary:

```
q)d:(enlist enlist `a)!enlist 4
q)d,:(enlist `a`b)!enlist 3
q)d,:(enlist `a`b`c)!enlist 1
q)d
,`a   | 4
`a`b  | 3
`a`b`c| 1
q)d`a
4
q)d`a`b
3
q)d`a`b`c
1
```